# gifsicle.exe on Windows 7 - Invalid argument error

Tags: windows-7, command-line, animated-gif

I'm trying to build a GIF image from several different GIF images using GIFSICLE.exe utility. Here is the link to the utility that I'm referring here: http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/

I've all the individual GIF frames saved in "Frames-GIFs" folder and the gifsicle.exe is also placed in the same folder. Here is the command line that I'm passing:

`gifsicle --delay=10 --loop *.gif > test.gif`

I'm getting following error:

`gifsicle: *.gif: Invalid argument`

Can someone please guide me to build a proper Command Line for gifsicle and make animated GIF using a series of GIF image files?

*P.S.: This is an attempt to make a Screen Recorder in Visual Basic that records screen activity in animated GIF image format. I've completed code that takes screenshots of predefined area at a preset frequency (delay parameter for gifsicle). If you can suggest any better alternative, your suggestions are welcome. :-)

Comment: Have the same issue. Looks like gifsicle ported badly to windows

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit binary of Gifsicle 1.83 by [Jernej Simončič](https://eternallybored.org/misc/gifsicle/) works for me on 64-bit Windows 7.

The 64-bit binary has the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please  try

```
gifsicle --delay=10 --loop * .gif > anim.gif
```

you may try also

```
gifsicle -d 10 --loop * .gif > anim.gif
```

then rename `anim.gif` to `test.gif`

Comment: 64-bit binary of Gifsicle 1.89 and 1.92 by Jernej Simončič have the same error